# AuthenticationError: <empty message> in OpenAPI api

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I have been trying to use langchain library's `ChatOpenAI`, I pip installed langchain, and imported `ChatOpenAI`

I'm running my code on colab so I set my the openAI's api key as:

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY= my_api_key
```

now when I try to initialize `ChatOpenAI` as follows, it runs without error:

```
chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0,openai_organization='Personal')
chat
```

I get the following as the result:

```
ChatOpenAI(verbose=False, callbacks=None, callback_manager=None, client=<class 'openai.api_resources.chat_completion.ChatCompletion'>, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo', temperature=0.0, model_kwargs={}, openai_api_key='my_api_key', openai_api_base='', openai_organization='Personal', openai_proxy='', request_timeout=None, max_retries=6, streaming=False, n=1, max_tokens=None)
```

But when I try to run it as :

```
customer_response = chat(customer_messages)
```

It throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AuthenticationError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a39359b08f39> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 customer_response = chat(customer_messages)

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/api_requestor.py in _interpret_response_line(self, rbody, rcode, rheaders, stream)
    761         stream_error = stream and "error" in resp.data
    762         if stream_error or not 200 <= rcode < 300:
--> 763             raise self.handle_error_response(
    764                 rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders, stream_error=stream_error
    765             )

AuthenticationError: <empty message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in authentication, make sure to use correct values for "openai.api_key" and "openai.organization" fields.

Also this code snippet may help you:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "your_api_key"
```